# Android ROM directory

Tags: android, directory, tablet, rom

I'm here to ask if anybody knows where's located the original ROM of an Android device, which will be loaded every time we make a factory reset.
I've been trying to find it at /Device directory through esExplorer in a rooted tablet but without success...

Anybody can help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to disappoint you, 
but unfortunately there is no such a thing.

usually, the factory ROM image is not stored on the device.

I which it was.

if some vendor decided to put such image - he can put it wherever he wants, and nothing prevents from the current installed ROM delete it entirely.

Comment: Ok, so beacause i've a Wolder miTab Neo tablet, which i can't find any ROM for it, there's no way i can install any other ROM on it or make a Custom ROM based on any other ROM, is that it ?

Comment: @MSerra: you can flush any specific rom to your device directly from the computer when inserting your device to download mode + using specific software like odin. you'll find lot's of tutorial how to do so. just search google for "install custom rom to Neo tablet with odin" or something like that